# Index error out of range python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

For some reason I am getting this error when trying to run the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
readFile = open('Out_0_0.txt','r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()
for plotPair in sepFile:
    xandy = plotPair.split()
    x.append(int(xandy[0]))
    y.append(int(xandy[1]))
print x
print y
```

When I remove the x.append and y.append lines and just put a print statement to print out what is in xandy it prints out each pair of values in the arrays fine. The text file has this

```
 1 2
 3 4
 5 6
 7 8
```

all I want it to do is store the first column in the x array and the second column in the y array

Comment: Why are you splitting the read on new line? `.read` will automatically read the lines one at a time. Do you maybe mean to do `.readlines`?

Comment: What error are you getting? When I run the code, I get `x = [1, 3, 5, 7]` and `y = [2, 4, 6, 8]`

Comment: I'm guessing (not sure) that you have an empty line at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Is it possible there is an empty line in the file? a carriage return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was in how you're reading in the file.

This will work.

```
x = []
y = []
with open('test.txt','r') as data_file:
    for plot_pair in data_file:
        xandy = plot_pair.split()
        x.append(int(xandy[0]))
        y.append(int(xandy[1]))
print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the file up in an editor like Notepad++ and make sure there are no extraneous lines at the beginning or end of the file you are reading.

Answer (score 3):

You can read this in a bit more efficiently (and safely). The first change I made was to use [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) when reading in the file. This will automatically handle closing the file when you are done with it.

Next, I've removed the `split('\n')` as it isn't required. We are, instead, going to loop over the file line by line and just split it at white spaces. Since this is a two column file, we'll do that with this line:

```
fx,fy = line.split()
```

I've stuck that in a try/except in case there is an empty line at the end of the file. That will produce a `ValueError` and the assumption is that this is the end of the file.

Then we append our columns for the row to the final array.

```
x = []
y = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            fx,fy = line.split()
        except ValueError:  
            break       
        x.append(int(fx))
        y.append(int(fy))

print x
print y
```

This prints out:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Finally, I've removed the matplotlib import. It wasn't required for this example.

Answer (score 1):

something quick... should work (not exactly tested :P)

```
x = []
y = []
with open(inputFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        nextX, nextY = map(int, line.split(' '))
        x.append(nextX)
        y.append(nextY)
```

Another quick thought: make sure the txt file has no empty lines at the end. Perhaps add a `if line:` check as well.